# Validador de Senhas em C

Tags: c, string, algoritmo

Estou tentando resolver o problema [2253 - Validador de Senhas](http://urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2253), do URI, porém está dando 10% de resposta errada, mas todos meus testes estão dando certo, alguém consegue achar o erro?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int validade(char *S) {
    int i, maiuscula = 0, minuscula = 0, numero = 0, tam = strlen(S) - 1;
    if(tam < 6 || tam > 32)
        return 0;
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        if(isupper(S[i]))
            maiuscula = 1;
        else if(islower(S[i]))
            minuscula = 1;
        else if(isdigit(S[i]))
            numero = 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return maiuscula * minuscula * numero;

}
int main() {
    char S[100];

    while(fgets(S, 100, stdin) != NULL)
        printf(validade(S) ? "Senha valida.\n" : "Senha invalida.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O maior problema é esse `while` que não faz sentido. Melhorei algumas outras coisas que pode dar algum ganho.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int validade(char *S) {
    int tamanho = strlen(S);
    if (tamanho <= 6 || tamanho >= 32) return 0;
    int maiuscula = 0, minuscula = 0, numero = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho - 1; i++) {
        if (islower(S[i])) maiuscula = 1;
        else if(isupper(S[i])) minuscula = 1;
        else if(isdigit(S[i])) numero = 1;
        else return 0;
    }
    return maiuscula * minuscula * numero;
}

int main() {
    char S[40];
    fgets(S, 40, stdin);
    printf(validade(S) ? "Senha valida.\n" : "Senha invalida.\n");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fpejHT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yeediocz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/PasswordCheck.c).

Comment: O problema exige o while porque a entrada do problema temina com final de arquivo, mas obrigado de qualquer forma.

Comment: Mas não faz sentido, porque esta função não retorna um fim de arquivo e sim um ponteiro.

Comment: @Alface, você pode perguntar à própria `stdin` se ela já terminou: `feof(stdin)`

Comment: Ou verificar [na documentação](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) que ele retorna `NULL` quando chega no fim do arquivo e não consegue ler 1 caracter sequer

Comment: Eu troquei para NULL e agora não excede o tempo limite, mas há 10% de resposta errada :/

Comment: Não faz sentido perguntar `EOF` direto no `fgets` com `stdin`. Quando trocou para `NULL` essencialmente fez o `while` não ser necessário mais, então faz o mesmo que a minha resposta, só que a minha não tem instruções desnecessárias. O objetivo desses exercícios é fazer aprender e não conseguir resolvê-los e não entender o que está lá.

Comment: Eu entendo o  que está lá, mas é que eu realmente preciso resolver como está lá, é um trabalho prático.

Comment: Bom, s´so você sabe o que está lá, e se é o que está falando, aquilo pede para fazer algo errado, ou então você está interpretando algo errado. Fica difícil ajudar mais que isto dado o que foi passado. A pergunta não falava nada disso, então o que foi perguntado já foi respondido.

Comment: Alface, seria mais fácil de explicar se você tivesse colocado um link ;-) Maniero, o Alface quer responder esse teste:https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2253. O código dele será validado por um arquivo contendo várias linhas, por isso o 'while'.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, resolvi a questão, eu só troquei de C para C++ e deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

Podes tentar usar um padrão RegEx para isso:

```
#include <regex.h>
```

E por exemplo usar como padrão:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,}$
```

Explicação:

```
^      inicio da palavra
(?=.*) "lookahead" procura para a frente
\d     numero
[a-z]  letra minuscula
[A-Z]  letra maiuscula
{4,}   pelo menos quatro caracteres
$      fim da palavra
```